# Remove drop shadow of an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, dropshadow

In Android Studio I integrated an ImageView with an unwanted drop shadow, which I cant seem to get rid off.
How do you make the picture blend in to the background? 
I tried setting the background of the button to transparent and `android:shadowRadius="0"` did not work.

[image: My ImageView]

My .xml file

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorWhiteText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.23" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:shadowRadius="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_174" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If this unwanted drop shadow is part of png then just remove it from png .

Comment: Are you using `ImageView` or `ImageButton` ?

Comment: is the ImageView inside a CardView? have you set any elevation?

Comment: It is not part of the png.

Comment: Seems like layout issue . Add your xml in question .

Comment: The ImageView is not in a CardView. Its directly in a ConstraintLayout and I did not set any elevation. I also tried the ImageButton and same thing applies.

Comment: add `android:elevation="0dp"`

Comment: You say in your question `" I tried setting the background of the button"`, but you don't have a `Button` you have an `ImageView`. The code as shown with dependencies set to `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'` **works** just fine with **no** drop shadow ! Maybe show the original image and edit your question to take out the word button.

Comment: One thing I did change was android:background="@color/colorWhiteText"    to android:background="#ffffffff" This maybe your problem as the background is important here.

Comment: what is logo_174? A vector_drawable or png image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found my stupid solution to this question. Make sure the picture itself has no drop shadow, which somehow wasn't the case. I was sure I had the picture as I wanted it to have it but somehow in the process a drop shadow was created.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `android:background="@color/colorWhiteText"` to `android:background="#ffffffff"` as the background is important here.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Maybe better form to set this in res\values\colors.xml:

```
<color name="windowBackground">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

and use:

```
android:background="@color/windowBackground"
```

Tests **ok** for me (no drop shadow) with dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: why to specific dependency?

Comment: @jitesh mohite the dependency is there for completeness, as there seems nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

1: You can check to value it is set

```
  android:background="@color/colorWhiteText"
```

2:  If your image is a PNG try using the below

```
 android:src="@drawable/logo_174"
```

3: If the image is a vector. SrcCompact is used for vector image support for devices less than API level 21

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

Note:The code shared by you is not giving any drop shadow when I tried.